# Alert when transferring files using SSH?

Tags: ssh, notifications

I transfer files through ssh, from one computer to another. Is there any way I receive a notification on my computer when someone tries to transfer files via ssh?

Comment: One approach is to configure the sshd deamon to verbose mode and keep a tab on logs.

Comment: people can bypass this alert, by transfering with other protocols. so why in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try by myself, but it should be possible to wrap the sftp executable. (check sshd_config for something like: `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`). It doesn't look to be setuid, so it can be a shell script wrapper. The rest depends on how it is called.

Comment: found some usefull information about this topic.http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45688/getting-notified-when-someone-logs-into-a-server-using-ssh-or-remote-desktop  thanks!